# 413 request entity too large

Tags: asp.net, iis, wcf, request, web.config

Eu tenho um serviço de emissão de notas que estava funcionando normalmente em uma VM no azure. Migramos para uma VM da Google e agora apresenta este erro quando a nota possui muitos produtos:

> 413 request entity too large

Já tentei várias possibilidades procurando no Google e verificamos que, a princípio, as configurações do Serviço e do IIS estão iguais nas duas VMs, mas a do Azure funciona e Google não. 
Esta pergunta pode parecer duplicada, mas as soluções que encontrei em outras questões do mesmo problema não me ajudaram.

Comment: Está passando os parâmetros pela url ao invés do POST, aí dá nisso! Provavelmente o servidor pode estar configurado para aceitar um número menor de caracteres do que antes.

Comment: Mas está por POST.

Comment: Se você habilitar o trace no serviço WCF, ele chega a logar a mensagem? Se não souber como habilitar pode ver nesse link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx
Pergunto isso para saber quem está limitando seu post, se é o IIS ou o WCF.

Comment: O mesmo WCF em outro servidor não apresenta esse erro. É a mesma publicação do WCF (mesmos arquivos) nos dois servidores e apenas no da Google apresenta o erro.

Comment: Se você tem a mesma aplicação e config, então provavelmente o problema é com o hosting na VM do Google. Já tentou obter suporte deles?

Comment: Ainda não tentamos suporte direto deles. Identificamos que ao tentar importar o serviço WCF instalado na VM da Google, apresenta um erro, mas ao apenas trocar o endpoint ele funciona (mas com o erro 413). Vimos aqui que o DNS da máquina foi trocado e talvez o IIS tivesse desconfigurado. Estamos reinstalando tudo e vendo se o problema é esse. Se não funcionar, procurar o  suporte da Google pode ser uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como última tentativa, resolvemos apagar todas as referências e usos do WSDL em nosso projeto e refazê-la, porém ao tentarmos deu erro. Identificamos que o erro era por um problema no DNS. Corrigimos o problema, atualizamos as referências e tudo voltou a funcionar normalmente.